# How can I write a rotation of a coordinate system alternatively a function formally correct?

Tags: geometry

The background of this question:

A triangle can be defined by the length of the three sides as an abstract object. This triangle can be embedded into the x/y plane of the three dimensional euclidian space with coordinates x/y/z.

Now the triangle is equally defined by the coordinates of the edges. Let one edge have the coordinates (0, 0, 0).

To start with, one side of the triangle can be selected to be the x-axis.

The triangle now can be rotated around the z-axis by an angle of phi. Likewise the coordinate system could be rotated by an angle of -phi.

The problem is: how can I formally rotate the coordinate system when there is no reference frame? I can imagine to define a first coordinate system as reference and the define a second coordinatesystem in the first one which now can be rotated independently of the triangle.

Now I should be able to independently rotate the triangle and coordinate system and calculate the coordinates of triangle in the secondary coordinate system.

That said, a vector (x, y, z) can be defined were x, y are the coordinates of the triangle while z = f(x, y) as shown below.

Let there be the graph of the function $$ z = f(x) = x $$

This is represented by a straight line at angle 45°

Let there be the graph of the function $$ z = f(x, 0) = x $$

This function is a straight line over the x, y plane

I now can rotate the function around the z-axis

$$ 
f (x, y) = x \cos\phi , x \sin\phi
$$

or I can rotate the coordinate system around the z-axis by an angle of $$ - \phi $$

So how can I write this formally correct.  I would like to have a natural coordinate system fixed, a second coordinate system that can be rotated to the first and a function that is defined in the second coordinate system.

If the function is just $$ f(x) = x \ \ \   or \ \  f(x) = x^2 $$
both rotations show the same result.

But this seems to be no longer the case for higher powers of x

[Rotational symmetry contour lines of $$f(x,y) = \sqrt(x^2 + y^2)$$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7sWU.gif)

[Nonrotational symmetry: contour lines of $$f(x,y) = x^4 + y^4 $$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdi0Y.gif)

Comment: What's $f$ when you write $f(x,0)$?

Comment: $f (x, y) = x \cos\phi , x \sin\phi$ is not a function whose value is a real number. What is it?

Comment: $f(x,y)=x+y$ doesn't have rotational symmetry either. You get rotational symmetry by making $f$ a function of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2},$ since $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the distance in the $x,y$ plane from $(0,0).$

Comment: @David: you are right. What do I want to understand: I'm used to rotate a vector or to rotate the coordinate system, e.g. in motor control (Clarke/Park). Now I realise that certain functions $$z=f(x,y)$$ create a 2-dimensional subspace that is symmetrical when rotating the function or rotating the coordinate system. Others don't have this property